# Alternate way to display usercontrols in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I'd like to know if there is an alternate way to display `usercontrols` inside `mainwindow` in WPF application. 
Currently I make use of the visibility property of `usercontrols` to display one usercontrol at a time on a button click. I set the visibility of the usercontrols to `Hidden` and on button clicks I change the visibility. It works perfectly. But is this the correct way to do this?

EDIT:

I tried something like this but it does not work.

```
mainwindow.xaml:

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="54*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="257*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,251,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
</Grid>

</Window>
```

There are two user controls namely-UserControl1 and UserControl2. In the code behind:

```
 private UserControl currentview;


    private UserControl CurrentView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currentview;
        }
        set
        {
            this.currentview = value;
            //RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
        CurrentView = uc1;
    }
```

It does not work. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a `ContentControl` (in the MainWindow xaml), and bind its content to a view so that you can switch it in your code. Like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="54*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="257*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>

    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,12,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,251,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
</Grid>

</Window>
```

In the code behind:

```
    private UserControl currentView;

    public UserControl CurrentView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currentView;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.currentView == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.currentView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am new to this. Can U pls explain where the currentView code is to be placed? Also I want the usercontrol displayed inside a Grid.

Comment: If you're new to C#/WPF and its MVVM style, I'd suggest looking at this fantastic SO question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish Also, to add it in a grid simply wrap a <Grid> around the <ContentControl> - I will edit the answer to show you.

Comment: I tried what u said. Could u pls tel me where I am going wrong? I have edited the Question

Comment: Hello, try adding your code-behind as a data context to your window and see if it helps (DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"), updated the answer also.

Comment: What does the `RaisePropertyChanged()` function do? I couldn't add its corresponding namespace

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing really wrong with it, if you are ok with your controls to stay in memory during the lifecycle of your window. Also, Amadeus Hein's answer.