# How main window can catch the NotifyPropertyChanged event of a property in its contained Usercontrol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a UserControl, it contained bool property A.
In main window, which contain that UserControl, I have to enable/disable a button depends on the value of A.
I tried to make A as public and binding button like this:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding MyUserControl.A}"/>
```

And in UserControl, I set PropertyChangedEventHandler for Property A like:

```
private bool _a;
public bool A
{
    get
    {
         return _a;
    }
         set
    {
         if (_a == value)
             return
         _a = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("A");
    }
}
```

It look fine. But I have no idea why it does not work.
It seems that I have lack of some implementation to communicate between main window and its usercontrol (because with OnPropertyChanged, all binding inside usercontrol work well).

I have some solution for that are
 1. Use Messenger to send a message from Usercontrol with the content is value of A, main control will catch & set value to IsEnabled of button.
 2. Make a event & raise it anytime value of A is changed.

Do you have any idea about this problems and how to fix it?
Do you think 2 below solutions will work well or you have any other recommendation?

### Thanks for reading.

<< Edit >>
This issue is solved. It is my mistake when set the datacontext of usercontrol in code-behind and do not recognize that I already set them in datatemplate.
--> So, duplication make 2 times initialization of viewmodel of usercontrol.
--> somehow, it make the NotifyPropertyChange work incorrectly.

I'm sorry the title of this question is not suitable for this silly mistake. It seems that I went on the right way to solve the question on title.
Thanks for your reading & your advices.

Comment: Did you try to define your `A` property as dependency property?

Comment: Does the binding works? you can set the tracelevel (IsEnabled="{Binding MyUserControl.A, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}") to check if the binding works

Comment: @Alexander Balte: I'm sorry, can you explain a little?

Comment: @rhe1980: yes, binding work well, i see no error related to binding on output windows.

Comment: @kidgu: where is your usercontrol (MyUserControl) instantiated? in xaml or in code behind? I tried it and it works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's my mistake. It work well now. So silly, sorry guy ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Alternate way to display usercontrol in wpf . Check this StackOverflow discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054249/alternate-way-to-display-usercontrols-in-wpf)

Alternate for INotifyPropertyChanged : Dependency property for binding.

//usercontrol

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
   public bool A
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

}

//Mainwindow.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
      Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
      <src:UserControl1 x:Name="myControl" />
      <Button IsEnabled="{Binding A, ElementName=myControl}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The binding exressions always use the the [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) as the base for the evaluation of the binding path. So in your case the `DataContext` must be the window itself, you could set it in the constructor of the window in the code-behind file:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Also note that to work your window  needs to have a property called `MyUserControl`.

Another option would be to give the MyUserControl instance that you might have instanciated in XAML a name and then use `ElementName` in the binding expression:

```
<Grid>
    <loc:MyUserControl Name="myUserControl" />
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding A, ElementName=myUserControl}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have to set the datacontext to the viewmodel of windows (i'm using mvvm). I also tried to use ElementName & Path instead of use myUserControl.A, but same phenomenon occurs (no binding error, but nothing occurs when I change value of A)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of UserControl by declaring an it in resources and set it into datacontext and then you can use it. Try this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <WpfApplication2:UserControl1 x:Key="MyUserControl"/>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource MyUserControl}">
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=A}" Content="Test" Height="20" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I initialize this usercontrol in viewmodel. i have just add additional information. Hope it more clear! Thanks for your comment!